# Is there any component to create graphical tab pages? (according to the picture)

Tags: delphi, tabs

Is there any component to create graphical `Tab Pages` like this?
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about those components:

- [IceTabSet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/icetabset/)
- [SmartTabs](http://rmklever.com/?p=273)

Both are with source, and will have the expected aspect.

If you search for a component, take a look at the [torry.net](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=165) web site. You probably will find your need here.

Comment: I don't know how to use `SmartTabs` !

Comment: Download the file, and the GDI+ libraries available at http://www.progdigy.com. Then uncompress all files in a custom directory, available in your IDE path. Then use the "Add component" menu from the IDE, select the rkSmartTabs.pas file, and the corresponding component will appear in a new "rmklever" tab.